# my problem in inverse laplace $\frac{1}{s}\arctan\frac{1}{s}$

Tags: laplace-transform

I want to find inverse laplace 
$$\dfrac{1}{s}\arctan\dfrac{1}{s}$$
My approach:
$$F(s)=\dfrac{1}{s}\arctan\dfrac{1}{s}$$
$$(sF)'=\dfrac{1}{s^2+1}$$
$$L(-ty')=\dfrac{1}{s^2+1}$$
$$-ty'=\sin t+C$$
$$y=-\int\dfrac{\sin t+C}{t}dt$$
how can i continue from here?

Comment: Remember that on MSE you should mark an answer as accepted if you think that the answer was what you were looking for! This, besides giving points to the users, let's all other users know that this forum is closed

Comment: @DavideMorgante I wanted to accept but it didn't allow before 5 mins.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Thank you!

Comment: No `\dfrac` in titles, unless they would be absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Did Sure thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, the integral $$\int \frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt$$ has no closed form: this is called the [sine integral](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj-obfNj7DcAhXECewKHcyRBAsQygQwAXoECAMQCA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FTrigonometric_integral%23Sine_integral&usg=AOvVaw2xCzbhYWJzEsK9ijkWhxul)

Comment: thnx. so is my answer correct?

Comment: Just a correction $$\mathcal{L}(sin(t))= \frac{1}{s^2+1}$$ no need for the $+C$

Comment: why, integration const.

Comment: The laplace transform is a definite integral.

Comment: The integral for the Laplace transform is not an indefinite integral

Comment: I believe you shouldn't write the answer as an indefinite integral either.